# Help translating artist names and signatures

Tags: character-identification, seal

I have a few pieces of art my grandmother brought from China in the 1980s. She and my grandfather were part of a group to canoe the yellow river and fell in love with the amazing country and culture. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show the whole painting?

Comment: From top to bottom: 師任堂，竹寿，余昌

Comment: Always take a clear picture of the seal. They’re much more useful than the calligraphy for identifying artists.

Answer (score 4):

The first one is 師任堂 which corresponds to the art name (號) of [a female Korean artist in the 16th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin_Saimdang). By identifying the corner, we can see that is a copy of this painting.[image]